# Prove that if $A$ has linearly dependents columns, then $A^tA$ is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just want to prove this statement without using determinants or rank properties; in fact, I want to see it using the fact that if $A$ has linearly dependent columns than $Ax = 0$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Actually, A is a m x n matrix.

Comment: Yeah, I was initially thinking about dependent rows. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ has linearly dependent columns, then there is an $x\ne0$ so that 
$$
Ax=0
$$
for that same $x\ne0$, we have
$$
A^TAx=A^T0=0
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Simple and clear. =)

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ has linearly dependent columns, then there is a non-trivial solution to $Ax = 0$.  Therefore, there is a non-trivial solution to $A^TAx = 0$.  This implies that $A^T A$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^{t\!}A$ is invertible (nonsingular), then
$$
(A^{t\!}A)^{-1}A^{t\!}A=I_n
$$
so $A$ has a left inverse and therefore the system $Ax=0$ has exactly one solution, which precisely means that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(c_1\cdots c_n)$ where $c_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. Since the column of $A$ are linearly dependent then there's $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in\Bbb R$ not all $0$ such that

$$\alpha_1 c_1+\cdots+\alpha_n c_n=0$$
hence with $x=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)^T\ne0$ we get $Ax=0$. Now obviously for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ $A(\alpha x)=0$ so there's infinitely many solutions and of course $A^TAx=A^T0=0$.